# How to solve "Error: Failed to initialize Google Cloud Firestore client with the available credentials."?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When trying to deploy my Firebase Cloud Functions with `Firebase deploy` I get the following error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: Failed to initialize Google Cloud Firestore client with the available credentials. Must initialize the SDK with a certificate credential or application default credentials to use Cloud Firestore API.
    at FirebaseFirestoreError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at new FirebaseFirestoreError (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:220:23)
    at getFirestoreOptions (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/firestore.js:96:11)
    at initFirestore (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/firestore.js:105:19)
    at new FirestoreService (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/firestore.js:43:32)
    at /functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:261:20
    at FirebaseApp.ensureService_ (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:351:23)
    at FirebaseApp.firestore (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:259:28)
    at FirebaseNamespace.fn (/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:327:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/functions/lib/users.js:6:27)
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Solution**

**UPDATE**

You can simply update your Firebase Admin by executing `npm i firebase-admin`. Thanks to @samthecodingman for the information.

**PREVIOUS**

One way to solve this problem is to downgrade the version of your Firebase Admin by executing `npm i firebase-admin@8.9.0` cause it seems to only affect version `8.9.1`.



**2. Solution**

Another way to solve the problem is to run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"` in the command line. 
The Google Application Credentials can you get by following these steps:

> 1. Open the [Service Accounts pane](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) of the Google Cloud Console.
> 2. Make sure that App Engine default service account is selected, and use the options menu at right to select Create key.
> 3. When prompted, select JSON for the key type, and click Create.

For more information see the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional)

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that if you pass in a configuration object to `admin.initializeApp(someObj)`, that the `credential` property must be set correctly.

Comment: Furthermore, there is a new v8.9.2 as of two days ago which apparently will fix this bug

Comment: Having the same issue did the above and still nothing is working. The weird thing is this was working no problem for the last few days. Only yesterday did it stop working.